# how can i communicate to google home mini device with android app or vise-versa

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Is it possible with Google home device listen our command -> which trigger action in our android app -> app fetch the rest api data according to command -> app parse the data and send response to google home device -> google home device tells/speaks the result.

Comment: Tonight my schedule is going to be affected as this question triggers my brain and would like to do a little bit of research on it because I am studying some sort of AI tools including TensorFlow. Thank you for your question though.

Comment: I don't think so, I think Google Assistant is only used for building smart home Actions, ant then let users control Internet of Things (IoT) devices through the Google Assistant.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Home cannot communicate directly with your Android device. All of its communication is done directly with a server. This server can communicate with an Internet-based webapp that you control using the [Actions on Google API](https://developers.google.com/actions/).

That said, there are various ways that you can make a server that communicates with your Android app to collect the information, or just have the webapp make the REST API call itself.